# Smoothing HEALPix maps with `healpy`: Why does the output map appear "patchy"?

Tags: python, astronomy, healpy

I have a HEALPix all-sky map, from the AKARI Far Infrared Surveyor databse (publicly released). I have tried to "smooth" the map using `healpy`, but the result looks very strange. Is there a better way? My question however relates to any all-sky HEALPix map (i.e. IRAS, Planck, WISE, WMAP).

My objective is to "smooth" the effective point-spread function of this AKARI map to an angular resolution of 1-degree (the original data has a PSF of about 1 arcminute). This is so that I can compare the far infrared AKARI map to lower resolution microwave maps (specifically, those of the *anomalous microwave foreground*).

In my example below, I'm using a degraded version of the map, so it'd be small enough to upload to Github. This means that the pixels are about 3.42 arcminutes. I wouldn't degrade the pixel scale so much, before PSF smoothing, normally- but this is just an example:

```
#Load the packages needed for visualization, and HEALPix processing
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import healpy as hp
import healpy.projector as pro

#Loads the HEALPix .FITS file into an array
map_in = hp.read_map("akari_WideL_1_1024.fits", nest = True)

#Visualizes the all-sky map, before any processing is done.
hp.mollview(map_in, title='AKARI All-Sky Map:', nest = True, norm = 'hist')

#Smoothes the map with a 1-degree FWHM Gaussian (fwhm given in radians).
map_out = hp.sphtfunc.smoothing(map_out, fwhm = 0.017, iter = 1)

#Visualizes the the map after smoothing
hp.mollview(map_out, title='AKARI All-Sky Map:', nest = True, norm = 'hist')
```

I have tried the healpy.sphtfunct.smoothing routine (https://healpy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/generated/healpy.sphtfunc.smoothing.html#healpy.sphtfunc.smoothing).As far as I understand, `smoothing` converts the map into spherical harmonics, then convolves with the gaussian, and then converts it back into a spatial map.

I've saved the ipython notebook as well as the low-res .FITS HEALpix map in a github repository, here:

https://github.com/aaroncnb/healpy_smoothing_test

(You'll need to have the `healpy` package installed)

By running the code in the notebook, you can easily visualize the trouble I'm having- after smoothing the map, there are some strange "artifacts", as if the pixels had been iteratively box-averaged, rather than smoothed with a circular guassian profile. What I expect to see, is just a blurrier version of the input map.

I think I'm missing something fundamental about the conversion to spherical harmonics, before the smoothing is done.

Has anyone tried to do this kind of all-sky smoothing before, on a HEALPix map?

I believe another option is to convert the map to a standard, rectangular array, and then conduct the smoothing. However I remain curious about solving the problem without leaving the HEALPix format.

Answer (score 2):

It appears `smoothing` works on a RINGed map only (it kind of makes sense to me, since this seems a bit easier to handle mathematically). Thus, you'll need to convert your input map to a RINGed format:

```
map_ring = hp.pixelfunc.reorder(map_in, inp='NEST', out='RING')
map_out = hp.sphtfunc.smoothing(map_ring, fwhm = 0.17, iter = 1)
hp.mollview(map_out, title='AKARI All-Sky Map:', nest = False, norm = 'hist')
```

[image]

---

This answer is from a bit of trial and error, because I can't find anything definitive on it in the documentation, and I haven't dived into the source code (though, with the below result, it may be easy to verify whether my assumption is correct by looking through the relevant source code).
Or, you may want to ask the healpix/healpy people directly.

(I'd suggest it is in fact a shortcoming in the documentation: the docs for `healpy.sphtfunc.smoothing` don't mention the required form for the input. I guess that's a healpy issue/PR for another day.)

Btw, bonus points for creating a SSCCE as a notebook file on Github! (Now if only StackOverflow also rendered notebooks.)